# Replace ">" and every character after the special character

Tags: php, preg-match

i am a beginner in PHP and would want to replace ">" and every other character after it in a string.

```
http://www.example.com/>testmail
```

Comment: This looks able to do what you want: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php
I haven't tested, but `preg_replace('/>.$/', 'replacement', $your_string)` should make it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
<?php
 $string = 'http://www.example.com/>testmail';
 $pattern = '/(>(.*?))$/i';
 $replacement = 'helloWorld';
 echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
```

More about preg_replace; http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using standard string functions:

SOURCE:

```
<?php
//init values
$str = 'tag>content';
$strReplace = '[stuff_here]';

//find 0-based index of angle-bracket char from start of string (if any)
$idxPos = strpos($str,'>');
if ($idxPos !== false)
{
    //lop off portion to right and append replacement
    $str = substr($str,0,$idxPos) . $strReplace;
}
//print result
echo $str . "\n";
?>
```

OUTPUT:

```
tag[stuff_here]
```